# Contenteditable отправляет пустое письмо, или как бороться со спецсимволами без wysywyg плагинов и jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, post

Есть `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`
При редактировании, копирует innerHTML в input, все отправляется через POST.
Заголовки

```
// js 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // JavaScript

// php
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

При этом в тексте генерируются спец символы в виде html кода. 
Например, пробел `&nbsp;`
При наличии спецсимвола, на почту отправляется пустое письмо.

**Как можно обрабатывать спецсимволы, чтобы сообщения приходили не пустые, при этом не устанавливая никакие wysywyg плагины и jquery?**

Пока только вижу вариант - писать регулярку для замены каждого спецсимвола перед отправкой.
Но, кажется, что если будут символы Меньше < или Больше > то собъется вся верстка письма.
Вопрос задан 8 часов назад  25 просмотров

Comment: Не очень понятно, где проблема сейчас. Вы задачу целиком и в деталях опишите.

Comment: Что вы поправили? :)